# Using <button type="submit"> as replacement of <input type="submit"> to submit forms, problems?

Tags: html, forms

`<button>` tags are more easily stylable than inputs, and I'm really in favor of using them. However I'm afraid some problems may arise.

From W3schools: `Note: If you use the <button> element in an HTML form, different browsers may submit different values. Use <input> to create buttons in an HTML form.`

I also read that IE has problems with this buttons. I'm only looking to use them as a replace for submit buttons, eg:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="post"/>
<button type="submit">
</form>
```

Will they work the same as submit buttons or will I have problems like unsupported browsers or anything else?

Comment: [Just as a suggestion don't rely too much on W3Schools...](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: Not that I disagree with w3schools here, but don't depend on their information. http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `button` element has had serious problems with IE, which used to have a very broken implementation. This still remains a concern. According to [MDN page on `button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/button), IE 7 is still very broken in this respect, sending wrong data upon submission.

But if your form handling does not depend on the name=value data that results from a `button` element, `button type=submit` is safe these days. For example, when you have only one such button in the form, you probably wouldn’t use the name=value pair for anything anyway.

Comment: So basically if I don't use the name and value attribute s (which I don't plan on using) it's ok for IE7?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't experienced any IE problems with a `<button type="submit">`, and at the very very worse, you can always attach an `onclick` event handler to it.

A `<button>` should be safe to use.

As a final note: w3schools is a wrong and misleading site. You shouldn't use it as reference for any sort of language. For PHP, there's the [PHP Manual](http://php.net), for JavaScript, there's [Mozilla Developer Network (or MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/). See http://w3fools.com to further understand why you should never use w3schools.

Comment: Thanks, so basically It'll work on all browsers alright? Since it's aimed for young people I don't think the IE7 or older proportion will be too great but I'd rather support it

Answer (score -1):

If you use

```
 
  <input type="submit" name="whatever" />
```

you can be assured it works as fine as the button counterpart; you'll have no browser incompatibility issue. 
And it is equally stylable. 
 
Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not equally stylable. It doesn't support :before and :after since it doesn't have any inner content. Also some browsers ignore the styling of submit buttons like iOS' safari. I know I can use <input> but I want to know of the consequences of using <button>